# Android Status bar color on different API Level

Tags: android, android-styles

I am trying to set Status bar colors but having trouble with different api level.

I want dark icon color and yellow background. I have set the version style but it is not setting up for API Level 21. Please have a look screenshot marked in red.

[image]

Here is the code

#### v23\styles.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/colorPrimaryBackground</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorPrimaryText</item>
    <item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">true</item>
</style>
```

#### Default styles.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/colorPrimaryBackground</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorPrimaryText</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do is possible for api>23
Try following code:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
 View decor = getWindow().getDecorView();
 if (shouldChangeStatusBarTintToDark) {
    decor.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR);
 } else {
    // We want to change tint color to white again.
    // You can also record the flags in advance so that you can turn UI back completely if
    // you have set other flags before, such as translucent or full screen.
    decor.setSystemUiVisibility(0);
 }
}
```

Comment: I see. So we can change the icon colors only api>23? what the code you provided will do?

Comment: Yeah you can do it for >23. The code I provided will do the same dynamically what you are already doing. Only difference is that for api less than 23 you can define behavior what you want to do or keep it as android default. That will do it on runtime